# What is the range for vkCmdDrawMeshTasksEXT's arguments, or how would I find out?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

As the title says, I'm struggling to understand the range of `vkCmdDrawMeshTasksEXT`'s `groupCountX`, `groupCountY` and `groupCountZ` arguments. This is specifically in a pipeline where I'm not using task shaders.

Comment: What are you struggling with? If you look at the [valid usage section for the function and just search for those variables](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCmdDrawMeshTasksEXT.html), it seems to spell things out pretty clearly.

Comment: @NicolBolas I had looked there, and all of the valid uses seem to be within the context of "VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS contain[ing] a shader using the TaskEXT Execution Model". Since I'm only using mesh shaders at the moment, and not task shaders, I don't think I am in that context. So I'm wondering if I've missed any other limits on those variables, other than being `uint32_t`.

Comment: What about the ones that say "If the current pipeline bound to VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS **does not contain** a shader using the TaskEXT Execution Model?"

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed those. I'm unsure whether to close this question or convert your comment in to an answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicol Bolas was completely correct in his comment on my questions, and I thought I'd make it in to an answer and close the question.

The [Vulkan 1.3 spec for vkCmdDrawMeshTasksEXT](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCmdDrawMeshTasksEXT.html) provides the following explicit requirements:

- If the current pipeline bound to `VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS` **contains** a shader using the TaskEXT Execution Model:

  - `groupCountX` ≤ `VkPhysicalDeviceMeshShaderPropertiesEXT::maxTaskWorkGroupCount[0]`
  - `groupCountY` ≤ `VkPhysicalDeviceMeshShaderPropertiesEXT::maxTaskWorkGroupCount[1]`
  - `groupCountZ` ≤  `VkPhysicalDeviceMeshShaderPropertiesEXT::maxTaskWorkGroupCount[2]`
  - `groupCountX * groupCountY * groupCountZ` ≤ `VkPhysicalDeviceMeshShaderPropertiesEXT::maxTaskWorkGroupTotalCount`
- If the current pipeline bound to `VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS` **does not contain** a shader using the TaskEXT Execution Model:

  - `groupCountX` ≤ `VkPhysicalDeviceMeshShaderPropertiesEXT::maxMeshWorkGroupCount[0]`
  - `groupCountY` ≤ `VkPhysicalDeviceMeshShaderPropertiesEXT::maxMeshWorkGroupCount[1]`
  - `groupCountZ` ≤  `VkPhysicalDeviceMeshShaderPropertiesEXT::maxMeshWorkGroupCount[2]`
  - `groupCountX * groupCountY * groupCountZ` ≤ `VkPhysicalDeviceMeshShaderPropertiesEXT::maxMeshWorkGroupTotalCount`

And there is the implicit requirement that the arguments be implicitly convertible to `uint32_t`s. I don't see any mention of what happens if any of the group counts are set to `0`, but I imagine, not much will happen.

For my specific set up the following values are defined, however these are by no means universal:

- `maxMeshWorkGroupCount[0]`: 4194304
- `maxMeshWorkGroupCount[1]`: 65535
- `maxMeshWorkGroupCount[2]`: 65535
- `maxMeshWorkGroupTotalCount`: 4194304